# htdocs folder not found in “/opt/lampp” after installing MySQL, PHP and Apache 2 successfully on Ubuntu

Tags: lamp

I have successfully installed Apache 2, MySQL and PHP.

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux(x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2019-08-26T13:43:29

php -v
PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.6 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.6,     Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

I want to save my files in `htdocs` folder but in my `/opt/` directory there is no `/opt/lampp/` directory.

```
bash-4.3$ pwd
/opt

bash-4.3$ ls
google
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## If you manually installed Apache 2, MySQL and PHP then the root directory should be in `/var/www/html/` and not in `/opt/lampp/`.

There are two ways to setup a LAMP server: By either installing individual packages as you have done which is the standard way or by doing some kind of non-standard install. The directory `/opt/lampp/` is not a standard LAMP install directory.  It seems like you are reading tutorials on how to deal with an [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/) installing which is a non-standard install.

So I would recommend just looking in the standard Apache directory of `/var/www/html/`. That is where you can add contents to your website on your setup.

Just note that if you don’t see `/var/www/html/` then just look in `/var/www/html/` and see what’s there; in some cases it *might* be a path like `/var/www/htdocs/`… But it definitely is not `/opt/lampp/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -iname "htdocs"
```

This assumes your distro uses that naming convention.

openSUSE uses `/srv/www/htdocs`

Open the Apache config file and look for `DocumentRoot` where does it say the root folder is located?

Alternatively you can edit the Apache config file containing `DocumentRoot` to point to any folder you want so long as you change permission on it accordingly.

Comment: I thought the same as you, but it seems like on  Ubuntu (possibly when using XAMPP?) the root should be at `/opt/lampp/`. Do a Google search for [“/opt/lampp/”](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=5EZtXbPyC-zK5gK_1p34DQ&q=%E2%80%9C%2Fopt%2Flampp%2F%E2%80%9D&oq=%E2%80%9C%2Fopt%2Flampp%2F%E2%80%9D&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30l10.1537.1537..4295...0.0..0.92.92.1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.J5q6h_byCx4&ved=0ahUKEwiz9N33yrLkAhVspVkKHT9rB98Q4dUDCAs&uact=5) to see what I mean.

Comment: @JakeGould  hmm Thats odd.  Oh well I guess they just had to be different.